# Prove that $S_2=S_3-S_4+2\Re S_5.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{u_r\}_{r\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Let $\{x_r\}_{r\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real numbers and define:
$$S_2=\sum_{s\neq t}\bar u_s u_t\, \sum_r' \csc \pi(x_r-x_s)\csc\pi(x_r-x_t),$$
$$S_3=\sum_{r, s, t}'\bar u_s u_t\, \cot \pi(x_r-x_s)\csc\pi(x_s-x_t),$$
$$S_4=\sum_{r, s, t}'\bar u_s u_t\, \cot \pi(x_r-x_t)\csc\pi(x_s-x_t),$$
$$S_5=\sum_{r, s}'\bar u_s u_t\, \cot \pi(x_r-x_s)\csc\pi(x_r-x_s),$$
where $\sum_r'$ denotes a sum in which the variables are restricted to exclude infinite summands.

Prove that
$$S_2=S_3-S_4+2\Re S_5.$$
An hint is:
$$\csc \pi(x_r-x_s)\csc\pi(x_r-x_t)=\csc \pi(x_s-x_t)\left(\cot\pi(x_r-x_s)-\cot\pi(x_r-x_t)\right)$$
because $r,s,t$ are distinct.